# A merchant gives a discount of 10% on the cost price of the tea, but uses a weight of 900 gm per kg. Find his net profit/loss percentage

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A merchant gives a discount of 10% on the cost price of the tea, but uses a weight of 900 gm per kg. Find his net profit/loss percentage

Uses a weight of 900gm per kg, does that mean he is incurring a loss of 100 gm?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the official price of a kilo is $x$, then we are paying $.9x$ and we get $.9$ kilos.

Therefore the price to mass ratio is the same as if the balance was correct and there was no discount.

Comment: Didn't understand it

Comment: :'( ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$ what is the problem?

Comment: $x/1000-x$ formula for faulty weights is giving the wrong answer . Can this formula be applied @hardmath

Comment: I don't understand your formula.

Answer (score 0):

The merchant is selling. So he profites when he gives less product.

So he sells 0.9kg for the price of 0.9kg, which is the same as not doing a thing.

He is not profiting or losing anything in the terms of money. He is profiting in the terms of appearing as if he is giving a discount but that is not a math issue, right?

Comment: Firstly, i do not understand your formula. Secondly, how does

   100/1000−1000∗100 equal 1.11??

Answer (score 0):

Look at the cases:

1) If the merchant sells $Q$ kilos at $P$ price per kilo without discount and with proper scales, then the profit is: $$profit=\frac{sales-cost}{cost}=\frac{PQ-PQ}{PQ}=0.$$

2) If the merchant sells $Q$ kilos at $P$ price per kilo with discount of $10\%$ and with proper scales, then the profit is: $$profit=\frac{sales-cost}{cost}=\frac{(0.9P)Q-PQ}{PQ}=-0.1$$

3) If the merchant sells $Q$ kilos at $P$ price per kilo with discount of $10\%$ and with improper scales (it shows $900$grams as $1$ kilo or $1$ kilo as $\frac{1}{0.9}\approx1.11$ kilos ), then the profit is: $$profit=\frac{sales-cost}{cost}=\frac{(0.9P)(\frac{1}{0.9}Q)-PQ}{PQ}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the price is $100\$\text{/kg}$. For a discount of $10%$, we get a price of $90\$\text{/kg}$. 
But because of faulty weights, we get only $900\text{g}$ instead of $1\text{kg}$. So, we get $90\$/0.9\text{kg}$, which is equivalent to $100\$\text{/kg}$.

Since $\text{CP=SP, Profit=0}$.